# Angular2 modular system break of modularity

Tags: angularjs

I present you the following code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/xxNW1xAIPoGtTK84OxGq

NOTE: This does not work because of SystemJS which I just can not configure. Whoever wants can edit if freely to make it work. I have been using the angular-cli and default webpack config and this works.

My question is about the "AlertService" which is needed to display an "alert". It has been extracted in the core module. However when I need to use it I have import it like so `import { AlertService } from '../core/alert/alert.service'` as present in `dashboard.component.ts` in order to inject it.

Doesn't this break the modular approach since I have to give it the path to the class ? If I change the location of the AlertService within the CoreModule I still have to go and change the string in the DashboardComponent. Also in this example if AlertService is not present DashboardComponent will not fire ... but DashboardComponent is part of the DashboardModule which should be able to start on its own - otherwise what is the point of the modules if they are coupled statically I could just put everything in one place.

What I want is to create a general alert component which I only need to include and once in the whole app and be able to use it everywhere.

But I think I am misunderstanding the concept of modules and/or how to use them. I have read the Modules' section in Angular.io multiple times and gone through multiple tutorials.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If having to change lots of file paths bothers you a lot, one possible solution is to add another layer - create a `services.ts` file, then have the canonical imports there rather than in each component. That way, you only have to update one file if you change the path:

services.ts:

```
import { AlertService } from './alert.service';

// ES2015 shorthand property initializer
export default {
    AlertService
};
```

yourComponent.ts:

```
import { AlertService } from "../services";
...
```

If you want a component to work even if a service is not present, you can [make it an optional dependency](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/core/di/metadata.ts#L71) (returning `null` if it doesn't exist), but TypeScript forces you to still have to import the service into the file to get code completion/typings. That's always felt a little janky to me.

Comment: Yes exactly ... If I have to statically import it from another component using a path it is not really modular since I am using the path. Right now I have the SharedModule defined yet if I want to use something from it I have to specify its path inside the SharedModule which to me is wrong.